# Angular FormControl strange behavior on Chrome version 80

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a formgroup and formcontrol in my component:

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
@Input() haveNds: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
    this.ndsSubscription = this.haveNds.valueChanges.subscribe((v: boolean) => {
    console.log('changed');
        if (v) {
            this.form.get('serial').enable();
            this.form.get('date').enable();
        } else {
            this.form.get('serial').disable();
            this.form.get('date').disable();
        }
    }
}
```

So, as you see I have subscribed to `haveNds` value changes. The problem is that when I toggle the value of `haveNds` first-time console logs `changed`, but doesn't enable `this.form` formcontrols. And after the first toggle, it just unsubscribes subscription and even `changed` is not logged in the console. This problem only happens Chrome version 80, but in other browsers, it works perfectly.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35190

Comment: Does this answer your question? [form.valueChanges doesn't emit values for disabled controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992910/form-valuechanges-doesnt-emit-values-for-disabled-controls)

Comment: @finki No, it doesn't. I solved it by using `this.form.controls.serial`

Comment: Well, the problem you described above was indeed a result of disabled form controls -> this was the reason your question was flagged as a duplicate. But hey, there are always different approaches ;)